# How to make single use setup file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, installation-package

I tried to make a single user software. How do I make a setup file with single user in Visual Studio 2010 or newer version?

I tried lots of ways but it does not work properly?

Comment: i try to set single use code

Comment: post here whatever you tried